# How can I sort arraylist hasmap

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

im wondering, how can I sort my arraylist:
its look like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>();
temp.put("Position", count);
list.add(temp);
```

I would sort by Position key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try it.

```
Comparator comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
Collections.sort(list,comparator);
```

And also check it.

[Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to sort the map entries by their keys, you can use a `SortedMap` (e.g. `TreeMap`):

```
List<SortedMap<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<SortedMap<String, ?>>();
```